# Using multprocessing.Pipe for blocking until event occurs (with timeout)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipc

I am using `multprocessing.Pipe` in a rather simple script that has 2 processes where ***A*** reads data from an external source (Arduino connected on a serial port) and sends and event to ***B***. This way I can make ***B*** block until it received that one specific event from ***A***, however the external source is not able to detect the even very reliably at times (it's ~75% reliable). So I would like to implement a time-out around this event, however I would like to drop an erroneous even that had already been timed-out, but nothing stops it from occurring

Is there a better abstraction that I can utilised for this purpose? One thing I'd like to be able to do is `b.recv(timeout=N)`, for some reason it's not currently possible with `multiprocess.Pipe`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `Connection`'s [poll method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Connection.poll); it has a timeout parameter:

```
receiver, sender = mp.Pipe()
...
if receiver.poll(timeout):
    data = receiver.recv()
```